# How can I fetch number and letter from string by re in python?

Tags: python

My string likes below

```
7930:
4487.
a5,77
```

It mix with number, letter and others. I just want get the numbers and letters, how can I write the re expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```
''.join(re.findall('[\da-zA-Z]', inputString))
```

[\da-zA-Z] will match any digit (\d), any lowercase letter (a-z), and any uppercase letter (A-Z).

findall will return a list of all matches, and ''.join will concatenate those matches into a single string.